# Is it possible to automatically call 'locationManager:didUpdateLocations:' delegate method after the user's current location changes?

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location, cllocationmanager, location-services

I'm developing an application that needs to constantly update user's location even in the background. Using `CLLocationManager`, is it possible to automatically call `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate method after the use's location changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to manually call the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate of `CLLocationManager`.

`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` is inherently designed to provide delayed GPS updates to save battery. So if you need updates immediately, implement the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` instead of 
`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.

All you need to do is create an instance of `CLLocationManager` object and call it's `startUpdatingLocation` method.

```
 self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
 [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]
```

After this, `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` will be called immediately when the user's location changes.

Also, as you need location the background too, do not forget to add the relevant capabilities in the plist. Also, for iOS9+, do not forget the below snippet

```
if (SystemVersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo(@"9.0"))
{
    self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}
```

Note: if you implement `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`, `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` will not be called. So do not implement both of them, only the one you need.

Comment: Thanks for update,but locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: method is deprecated in iOS 9.0

Comment: @SachinKumaram locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: has been deprecated since iOS 6. But its support hasn't been removed it because I think there is no other way to get instant updates (locationManager:didUpdateLocations: provides deferred updates). We still use locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:  in a bunch of Apps in which we need instant and accurate location updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  startUpdatingLocation() method of CLLocationManager class as per following

```
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

When ever instance of your viewController active in memory this method will be called but in background case after some time OS (iOS) removed app from background when other application not getting efficient memory space for the execution.

For background execution you can put your code in background task block as per following

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
        // Uh-oh - we took too long. Stop task.


    }];

// Perform task here
// Your code

 if (taskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskId];
    }
```

Hope this will helpful to you:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call

```
[LocationManager startUpdating];
```

Every time when location is updated, There is a simple solution for this provided by Location Manager its self.
You will get desired functionality with

```
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;
```

//Location manager will update you when location is changed to 10 meters.

Comment: will not work if you have clawed [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];